# How to translate "this person is salty or this person is feeling salty"

Tags: translation

For example, I had a flu shot but a week later I got the flu. I feel salty that I went through the trouble of getting the shot and still ended up sick.

Another example, I stood in line for the new iPhone for hours but it just became sold out when I am almost next in line.

Both 吃亏了，or 气死了。does not feel like it captured its meaning.

Comment: I'm not sure what "salty" means in your example. Do you want a vocabulary to describe the feeling after bad luck? or to describe, I quote from the Urban Dictionary, "A phrase people say to someone when they are doing/has done something stupid or embarrassing", which in my opinion does not quite fit your example?

Comment: @Agrit In 3.1 [Angry or resentful, especially in response to a defeat or disappointment.](https://www.lexico.com/definition/salty).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to consider it as you were feeling 沮丧.

Answer (score 1):

I just think this for a while. I don't think we have such an expression which can be used in modern conversation and express the exact thing "salty" means.

But I really got one which is "恼恨", it's quite formal. "恼" means angry, "恨" means hateful, these united suggest the anger because of a hateful thing, and this hateful thing may be a defeat or a disappointment or other something.

But it's really farfetched to call the feeling in your examples as "Hate". Although you can use "恼恨" to express your resentful, but the listener will think "Oh, this one is really fussy."

In your particular usage, I think "可恶" or "可恨" is a precise one. Formally both of them mean hateful, but in oral or on the internet it means annoying and suggests a kind of anger.

Edit:

You can only use "可恶/ 可恨" when stating things happened on yourself:

> 可恶, 排了半天队结果卖完了.
>
> D**m, I waited such a long time and got nothing, they've sold out. (I don't know how native speaker say things like this)

If you want to describe things happened on others, you must choose the biggest part of your emotion to show your attitude about his experience:

> 他去排了半天队结果卖完了, 可气死他了/ 他可伤心了/ 他都服了.
>
> He waited so long and bought nothing because they've sold out, that makes he angry/ sad/ can't believe it. (also don't know if you really say this)

But "恼恨" can be used in both way, just make others feel a little bit werid:

> 他去排了半天队结果卖完了, 这令他感到恼恨.
>
> He feels salty because He'd waited such a long time and got nothing for they sold out. (still not sure)
>
> 我去排了半天队结果卖完了, 这令我感到恼恨.
>
> I feel salty because I've waited such a long time and got nothing for they sold out. (still not sure)

Answer (score 1):

**气恼**(angry and resentful) might be the word you are looking for. E.g.

> 排了这么久队还没买到iPhone, 真让我气恼！
>
> 我女朋友很气恼，我没陪她一块逛街。
>
> I feel salty that I went through the trouble of getting the shot and still ended up sick. // 我费了这么大的劲去打了针，结果病还没好，我很气恼。

Answer (score 0):

In Taiwan, sometimes, some people use 嘔 to describe this kind of situation that it is such a shame to lose something which they expect someone or themselves to get, for example:[但就是很嘔當初怎麼沒有把握機會](https://www.dcard.tw/f/entertainer/p/228601215), [聯電心裡一定很嘔](https://ec.ltn.com.tw/article/paper/1306053), [唯獨這一對夫妻有緣報名，無緣參加，好嘔](https://fang9763.pixnet.net/blog/post/265456550-%E5%BE%88%E5%98%94%E7%9A%84%E5%A4%AB%E5%A6%BB)

Answer (score 0):

**酸**

Chinese salty is tart.

There's a [tweet](https://twitter.com/zhaolewisliu/status/718072775773130752) here that also explains it this way:

> 今日英语 salty：酸。字面意思是咸的，含盐的；但常用来指某人轻微嫉妒或心里难过的感觉，即很酸，酸溜溜的，酸不垃圾的，心里苦的。

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion of this sentence

“this person is salty or this person is feeling salty”

is just like when i feel something and in some next days i got

for example

i have a dot of rash in my skin [image]

and after some days my skin is full of rashes

like [image]

in my way this is best way to explain this sentence